# Passing an id in Django url

Tags: django

I want to pass `userid`   from django url to my view

Here is what I have written in Django template

```
<a href ={% url 'user_details' x.id  %} class='btn btn-primary' style="float: right;" >Know More</a></div>
```

To handle this url I have written Url like

```
url(r'^User/(\d{userid})/$', 'search.views.user_detail',name='user_details'),
```

But I am getting an error i.e

```
NoReverseMatch at /search/

Reverse for ''user_details'' with arguments '(2L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Please help me out What might I am doing wrong here .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No quote `''`

```
<a href ={% url user_details x.id  %} class='btn btn-primary' style="float: right;" >
    Know More
</a>
```

Another your url

```
url(r'^User/(?P<userid>\d+)/$', 'search.views.user_detail', name='user_details'),
```

Comment: Since userid is a number actualy so Y can't use d instead Of P in URL

Comment: About your question, I don't know I never encountered like that. I just follow what I learn in book :)

Answer (score 11):

Be carefull, after Django 1.5, use must use quotes. I came across this solution and tried it, got an error. I'm using Django 1.6 and you need the quotes:

```
<a href ={% url 'user_details' x.id  %} class='btn btn-primary' style="float: right;" >
    Know More
</a>
```

hope it helps.