# Passing an id to a url link - Django

Tags: python, django

I need to pass a `cluster_id` in my `show.html` page, in case the user wishes to halt a cluster created. My `urls.py` looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from clusters import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^show/', views.show, name='show'),
    url(r'^login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^destroy_clusters/', views.destroy_clusters, name='destroy_clusters'),
    url(r'^halt_clusters/(?P<cluster_id>\d+)/$', views.halt_clusters, name='halt_clusters'),
    url(r'^check_log_status/', views.check_log_status, name='check_log_status'),
    url(r'^read_cluster_log/', views.read_cluster_log, name='read_cluster_log'),
]
```

and in my `show.html` I have:

```
{% for cluster in clusters %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">{{ cluster.id }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url halt_clusters cluster_id=cluster.id %}">Halt</a></td>
        <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

so when I execute the webpage, I have:

```
NoReverseMatch at /clusters/register/
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'cluster_id': 19L}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

and this is driving me crazy!! Why can't I just pass the id there? I looked this example: [Passing an id in Django url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608295/passing-an-id-in-django-url) but it doesn't seem to work for me. Help?
My `Django` version is `1.8.dev`

Comment: what django version are you using?

Comment: @stalk updated the question with the django version

Comment: I suppose you need [to add quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22718055/821594)

Answer (score 1):

In recent Django's you should quote literal URL names in the tag:

```
{% url "halt_clusters" cluster_id=cluster.id %}
```

Otherwise Django will look for `halt_clusters` variable in your context and use its value as the URL name.

Oh, and while you're at it, you don't have to specify the keyword parameter name, so this should work as well:

```
{% url "halt_clusters" cluster.id %}
```