# Using Django for a very simple website: is it worth it?

Tags: django

Hello everyone how is it going?

I've just started using Django recently, and I've started getting my head around it; I need to build a website about cars, with two major APPS:

CarsCatalogue;

News Section;

I find the fact that I can manage the news from the admin panel extremely useful. I have created the typical model:

```
class Post(models.Model):       
title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
date = models.DateTimeField()
body = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

With the urls.py as follows

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(
   model = Post,
   template_name="news/post.html"))

url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(                                                    
                                queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],         
                                template_name="news/news.html")),
```

This is great! I can manage the News app Extremely easyly from the admin panel. Now I have a page for each news: news/1; news/2 etc etc;

But when i go down to the CarsCatalogue, and I would really need to simplify my life because I have plenty of cars with a personal page each to add, I am instead finding myself needing to modify the urls.py for each car I need to add, and it seems I have to modify the views.py for each car -I am using render- am I right?

***I mean, does it make sense to have a Views.py with one hundred different functions calling one hundred pages? 
And then if I want to create a list with all the urls of the CarCatalogue, having to write every link one by one?
Is this the way to use Django in this case?***

I would create another "news-style" APP for CarsCatalogue, that would be so much more easy for me to manage through the Admin Panel, but I need each url to show the car name, like: CarsCatalogue/Seat-Ibiza and not like CarsCatalogue/1.

Maybe I can do something like the news APP, but changing the way urls are generated and shown?

I am asking you all of this after I read the documentation and several Google topics and other resources; 
I hope you guys will be able to clear the fog around my head;

With all the Respect such a community deserves,

Sincerely,

-oKi

EDIT n*1

It's been 3 hours of reading, trying, modifying, erasing, trying again. 
I read a lot of stuff, but at the same time I got pheraps even more confused, because I found so many things while looking for how to "slug"ify the urls (that is indeed what I was looking for [now I can indeed use the admin panel to do what I wanted!] thanks) that I ended up mixing a lot of stuff. So, using the NEWS application, what I have done so far:

python3.5 manage.py flush, makemigrations, migrate, createsuperuser

I modified the news/models.py, so that it now looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Post(models.Model):           
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(title, max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.title)
```

I modified the news/admin.py, so that it now looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from news.models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": (Post.slug)}  <!-- that seems makes sense looking at the Model - I also tryed {"slug": (title,)}, {"slug": (Post.title)}-->
```

I modified the news/urls.py, so that it now looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Post 

urlpatterns = [ 
            url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(                                                    
                                queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],         
                                template_name="news/news.html")),                           

            url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', DetailView.as_view(
                                model = Post,
                                template_name="news/post.html")),
        ]
```

then I give:
python3.5 manage.py runserver
and it runs with no problem. 
So I go to /admin, I create a new post, it creates it...
But then what happens? 
It still uses the old "paradigm" to generate the url, including the old keys(id's) it was using before I erased the client... so... what I expected to be something like mysite/news/new-human-level-urld-news 
turns out to be mysite/news/11.

LOL :D and, luckily, the browser gives me also an error...

"FieldError at /news/11
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: body, date, id, title"

at the moment I can't find an answer, I find so much stuff that I just don't know how to mix things up. I will keep searching. Help is appreciated! Thanks for now!!! :D

Comment: You need to give a bit more information. You certainly shouldn't need 100 URLs - what do you need to change in each car page?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your Answer! I am using Jinja extending my header, so is not that I am creating all the page from scratch;
Each car page will have couple of photos/slides, a video from youtube, paragraph text, and some more personalization according to the model.
Thanks!

Comment: I need it so that I can post on socials etc "human friendly" links such as "website.car/CarsCatalogue/aston-martin-db"! 

I have a templates/CarsCatalogue folder that I guess I then need to define in the urls.py, and render through views.py.
Or at leas I guess! :O 

Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, but you still only need one url pattern - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix my problem.

Even though I started off by asking about the CARS Catalogue, I will explain what I did using the NEWS APP instead, as the logic is the same and as that is the APP I have modified in the first EDIT of my post. 
Inside the Templates, have a "news.html" page to render the list of all the Post, and a "post.html" to render every single Post.

The following is part of the procedure on how to set an APP that you can manage directly from the ADMIN PANEL, and that uses the SLUG field as URL.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):           
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from news.models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Post
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Post

urlpatterns = [ 
                url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(                                                    
                                queryset=Post.objects.all(),            
                                template_name="news/news.html")),                           

            url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', DetailView.as_view(
                                queryset=Post.objects.all(),
                                model = Post,
                                template_name="news/post.html")), 

        ]
```

I hope that can be useful to somebody.

Jeez you gotta study hard to use this Framework :D

Thanks everybody for the support, c ya :)

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding to your problem, what you need is not to create a view function for every car you have.
Indeed, you need to create 1 template (html page) that describes your CarsCatalogue, where all the CarsCatalogues have the same structure with different information. Then the user chooses one CarsCatalogue, let's say from a dropdown control and then you load the data from your database and show your results in the template.
In order to achieve this, have a look on the following topics:
[Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/). And in order to get your data from the database, you need the the id for example to be passed in the url, you can see this answer [how to pass an id in django url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608295/passing-an-id-in-django-url) or from the official website [URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/).

In few words, django is a simple way to do your website and definitely no need to rewrite your code several times.

Answer (score 0):

> NO THERE IS NO NEED TO CREATE MULTIPLE URLS.

From what I understood, you want a catalogue for each car.

Just create a view from where you display the names of all your cars.

Then when you click on a car, make a get request to another view function in the get request pass your selected car details. Now comes the use on Django Templates. Create a Django template for your catalogue, pass the car specific data to it.

You need to read about Django Templates , I think Django templates is something that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you're missing is that the parameter in the URL can be anything, not just a numeric URL. If it's a string, we call that a slug, and the Django admin will automatically create a slug from the fields in your model if you set the [`prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) option.

Then, you can use that slug in the URL:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', DetailView.as_view(
   model = Car,
   template_name="news/car.html"))
```

and Django will use that field instead of the ID to find the right content to display.

Comment: I really think this might solve my problem. I will now work with the new info you've just given me, studying what you suggested, and then I will let you know. Rep added, Thank you so much.

Comment: the situation has evolved! I posted it in the first post with an Edit. Cheers.

Comment: You need to add an actual field called "slug" to your model.

Comment: isnt't ok the one I added? 
slug = models.SlugField(title, max_length=100, unique=True)
I even added a function to slugify the title

Comment: But the error you posted talked about News, not Post.

Comment: Inside templates/news I have news.html(used for ListView) and post.html(that I use with DetailView). 
Then, Post is also the name of a class of models.py, where I have added  slug = models.SlugField(title, max_length=100, unique=True). The problem only presents itself when i am using DetailView !

Comment: Sorry, I am very confused. You started off asking about Car. Why have you changed anything to do with News/Post?

Comment: Because the News APP already had all the logic I wanted to apply to the Car APP, but I couldn't for SEO reasons, until you told me about the slug field. So I wanted to test everything on News APP before touching CAR. I understand things are getting messy, sorry. I am gonna start a new project from scratch and see how it goes. Keep you updated. thanks.